# Why does TPM think I installed a new CPU?

Tags: windows, boot, cpu, repair, tpm

I disassembled then reassembled a computer, I rebooted and got a message saying that I installed a new CPU or reset the NV structure. I don't really think I did either, there was only one RAM slot and the CPU was soldered in place. It says I can either reset the fTPM or boot. It also says I can use a recovery key from the "old cpu".

It boots, however, Windows doesn't seem to want to shut down without `Shift`-clicking the shut down button (it sort of pretends to shut down, then brings me right back to the start screen, the background does not even change).

I have a few questions:

1. Is the machine currently secure booting?
2. What will happen if I reset the TPM? Will I be able to boot?
3. Windows has robust support for TPM's (SecureBoot was mostly a Microsoft thing), so I think Windows might handle (2) well, but I am unsure about GNU/Linux distros. In the past I have had a lot of difficulty with using SecureBoot when booting Linux (especially with the proprietary Nvidia driver binary blob). I use a mainstream distro rn, with default support for SecureBoot, will it likely have a robust enough implementation to handle this (such that I wont be locked out of my OS or have too many driver issues when SecureBooting).
4. If I did (I dont) have keys, like for password less sign in on the machine, based on TPM keys, or disk encryption secured with the TPM, would this make those irrelevant
5. What else could I do to fix this (secure boot if its not secure booting), I am relatively sure I plugged everything back in. Everything seems to be working?
6. What may have caused this?
7. Why wont windows shut down normally?

Comment: Your TPM is handled by a firmware based TPM implementation, a feature, supported by your processor.  Your system does not have a physical TPM. If you were not using using the TPM for BitLocker, it's unlikely, resetting the TPM will have any affect on your system.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I guess I am trying to get at how robust a linux distro (with SecureBoot support) might be, see my other questions, I have gone through a lot to ensure that linux will work (+ the nvidia proprietary drivers) with secure boot. My impression in the past that support was somewhat "fragile", however I use a major distro now that has built in support, but I don't know how it will handle resetting tpm keys.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you, and I assume you mean that for the different cases I listed?

Comment: What different case?

Comment: `If I did (I dont) have keys, like for password less sign in on the machine, based on TPM keys, would this make those irrelevant` @Ramhound Or say, in the case of disk encryption

Comment: Is that a very complicated way of saying you were NOT using BitLocker?

Comment: @Ramhound More like I would account weigh this into a decision before trying it.